# Best practice recommendation for where to locate SPFx ReactJS component code?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

In looking at various SPFx tutorials/samples, I've noticed different paradigms demonstrated for where to locate the ReactJS component code.  For example, [Patrick Rodgers' tutorial on transitioning to @pnp/sp from sp-pnp-js](https://youtu.be/oAZX2_DFVjY) vs [a React sp-pnp-js web part included among the SPFx samples](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-async-await-sp-pnp-js/src/webparts/asyncAwaitPnPJs).  Both achieve a 'Hello World' flavored SharePoint query, but using very different syntax.

Patrick's example houses the pertinent code within the .ts file, and his project does not even appear to have a .tsx file or /components folder at all.  José Quinto's sample, on the other hand, utilizes the 
componentDidMount function within the .tsx file for the pertinent code.

As a newcomer to the SPFx framework, I'd like to know whether one or the other is a preferred 'best practice' - and why.  Or is this just a case of personal developer preference?

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others that are looking, I really liked this guy's response from the [community convo](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Developer/Best-practice-recommendation-for-where-to-locate-SPFx-ReactJS/m-p/152658#M4262) I started.

> I think it probably comes down to personal preference, experience with
>   the Spfx technology stack etc. We have found the most effective
>   development process to be:
>
> - develop React/Redux components in their own React specific library (using StoryBook to demo). Use mocked up services in this library to
>     represent the data that will be accessed in SharePoint
> - include that library in the Spfx TypeScript project, and reference the root React/Redux component in there
> - develop the genuine services to interact with the data in the TypeScript project (using PnP JS core)
>
> We find segregating the presentation components into a pure React
>   library increases efficiency, because the development experience is
>   more smooth. Spfx has been a big improvement, but "gulp serve"-ing
>   everytime you want to see the result of a code change is nowhere near
>   as rapid as using Storybook and having the page auto-update on every
>   code save.
>
> Because of this our end TypeScript project only has a single component
>   in root the tsx file (which loads the root component of the React
>   project), but has a Services directory containing the services and
>   their related interfaces.
>
> Hope that makes (some) sense.

Answer (score 2):

Both tutorials have tend to teach different things.

1. The first tutorial creates hello world web-part. What you will get to  introduced are SPFX web-part structure, .ts files are typescript files which are similar to .cs files in C#. The author also introduced the recommended pnp js library( replacement for rest API's).

**Summary**: Introduction to Typescript, pnp js    , If you are interested in learning typescript start [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)

2. The second tutorial uses .tsx files which are .jsx files under the hood. This part introduces you with React js, which is a JavaScript front end framework. React takes Component approach for building views of a web based application. Start [here](https://reactjs.org/) with react, if you are interested in developing spfx web-parts using React as the front end framework. Though you are free to choose any other framework like Angular, Backbone, etc as well.